# Updating many-to-many relational data with attach() from multiple checkboxes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am creating an online bookstore in Laravel, and upon creating a new book, the administrator is able to define which warehouses that are able to stock this book, by checking the specific warehouses checkboxes.
To give insight in how it works, this is my create function:

```
public function create()
{
    $authors = Author::all();
    $selectedAuthor = Book::first()->author_id;

    $publishers = Publisher::all();
    $selectedPublisher = Book::first()->publisher_id;

    $warehouses = Warehouse::all();
    $selectedWarehouse = Book::first()->warehouse_id;

    return view('books.create', compact(['authors', 'publishers', 'warehouses'],
                    ['selectedAuthor', 'selectedPublisher', 'selectedWarehouse']
    ));
}
```

and my store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'ISBN' => 'required',
        'author_id' => 'required',
        'publisher_id' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        $book = Book::create($request->all());

        foreach ($request->checked as $value){
            $book->warehouses()->attach([$value]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('books.index')
            ->with('success','Book created successfully.');

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        var_dump($e->errorInfo);
    }
}
```

But when an administrator edits a book, the checkboxes that were checked upon creating the book, should be "checked", and the administrator should be able to attach more warehouses, and be able to "unselect" a warehouse, so if an already checked value gets unchecked and sumbitted, it should get detached from the many-to-many table.

This is what i currently have:
My edit method:

```
public function edit(Book $book)
{
    $authors = Author::all();
    $selectedAuthor = Book::first()->author_id;

    $publishers = Publisher::all();
    $selectedPublisher = Book::first()->publisher_id;

    $warehouses = Warehouse::all();
    $selectedWarehouse = Book::first()->warehouse_id;

    return view('books.edit', compact(['book', 'authors', 'publishers', 'warehouses'],
                    ['selectedAuthor', 'selectedPublisher', 'selectedWarehouse']));
}
```

And my update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    $request->validate([
        'ISBN' => 'required',
        'publisher_id' => 'required',
        'author_id' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
    $book->update($request->all());

    // TODO: Update warehouses

        return redirect()->route('books.index')
            ->with('success','Book updated successfully.');

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        var_dump($e->errorInfo);
    }
}
```

And the checkboxes in my edit.blade view:

```
@foreach($warehouses as $warehouse)
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $warehouse->id }}">
    {{ $warehouse->address }}
    <br/>
@endforeach
```

My Book model:

```
public function warehouses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Warehouse::class);
}
```

And my warehouse model:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

Any help on being able to attach / detach upon editing an existing book, would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried sync() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on create and update method for storing

```
// Your method
foreach ($request->checked as $value){
    $book->warehouses()->attach([$value]);
}

// Try This
$book->warehouses()->sync($request->checked); // $request->checked must be an array
```

Update Blade

```
@foreach($warehouses as $warehouse)
    <input @if($book->warehouses()->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse->id)->exists()) checked @endif type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $warehouse->id }}">
    {{ $warehouse->address }}
    <br/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This works perfect!, do you know how to display the already checked warehouses on my checkbox list in the edit.blade view ? as right now, when editing a book, all checkboxes are unselected.

Comment: Well.. this actuaally updated them, so in order for this to fix the problem, i need the checkboxes that are currently active in the many-to-many table, to be preselected when editing a book.

Comment: I was updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I will left this example with a logic according your problem. In this case are roles:

```
public function edit(Role $role){
        //get roles ids
        $permission_role = [];
        foreach($role->permissions as $permission){
            $permission_role[] = $permission->id;
        }
        //get permissions
        $permissions = Permission::all();

        return view("role.edit", compact('role', 'permission_role', 'permissions'));
    }
```

In the blade:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Select the permissions for the current role</label>
        @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
        <div class="valid-feedback d-block" style="font-size: 15px !important;">
            <input  type="checkbox" value="{{ $permission->id }}" name="permissions[]"
                @if(is_array(old('permissions')) && in_array("$permission->id", old('permissions')))
                        checked
                @elseif(is_array($permission_role) && in_array("$permission->id", $permission_role))
                checked
                @endif>
            <strong> {{ $permission->description }} </strong>
            </div>   
            @endforeach
        </div>

            <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
            @foreach ($errors->get('permissions') as $error)
                   
                    {{ $error }}
                @endforeach
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of this way you can also keep the old checkboxes when nothing is select. You should validate it as required.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense, and great to see some validation on this subject.